# Printing the contents from powerpoint in an Excel file using VBA

Tags: vba

Im looking for a way to copy the text of the first element of a powerpoint slide into an excel file. I got the following code that prints out the text of the first box:

```
Sub getText

 Dim sld As Slide
 Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
 For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
 With sld.Shapes(1)

  myInput = .TextFrame.TextRange.Text
  MsgBox (myInput)

 End With
Next
End sub
```

Now the next step I want to take is to add the data to an excel file. Therefore I try to do the following:

```
Sub getText()

 Dim xlApp As Object
 Dim xlWorkBook As Object
 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 xlApp.Visible = True
 Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("~\PROJECTEN\Lopend\office_VA\macroStore.xlsx", True, False)
 xlWorkBook.sheets(1).Range("A2").Select


Dim sld As Slide
Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
With sld.Shapes(1)

 myInput = .TextFrame.TextRange.Text
 ActiveCell.Text = myInput

End With
Next

End Sub
```

However when I try it now it get the error: "Object required". Any thoughts on how I should change my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're referencing **ActiveCell.Text** but VBA has no clue what that is.  Also, you haven't declared your **myInput** variable.

Try this macro, where instead of selecting the cell I'm just assigning the text value to it.  Also, if you're writing more than one value your code will keep writing over the same cell.  In the code below I've added a couple of lines that will write your text down column A.

```
Sub getText()

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWorkBook As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("~\PROJECTEN\Lopend\office_VA\macroStore.xlsx", True, False)

    Dim xlWorkSheet As Object  ' Create a worksheet object
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.sheets(1)  ' Set the sheet you activate to that object 

    Dim iRow As Long  ' Create a variable to store row number
    iRow = 1  'Set the first row that you want to start writing data on

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim myInput As String
    Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        With sld.Shapes(1)
            myInput = .TextFrame.TextRange.Text
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(iRow, "A") = myInput  'Using .Cells() you can specify the (row, column) location
            iRow = iRow + 1  'increment by one for next line of text 
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Philip, thanks a lot for your thorough reply. However when I try it: i get fault 91 error a this line: xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.sheets(1). It says that the object variable or variable with is not configured good.... Any thougts?

Comment: Instead of using xlWorkBook.sheets(1) try xlWorkBook.sheets("Sheet1"), or whatever the sheet name is in your workbook.

Comment: Tried it and now I get a 438 error saying that this object does not support this method / configuration

Comment: What version of PowerPoint are you using?  What OS are you using (Windows, Mac OSx, etc)?